# Duda con operator==

Tags: c++

¿Teniendo el siguiente operador declarado en una clase cadena, sería correcto usarlo en una clase partido de la siguiente forma?

Operador:

```
  bool CCadena::operator==(const CCadena& obj) const {
  return strcmp(m_pText, obj.m_pText) == 0;
}
```

funcion:

```
if(m_nomLocal==nomEquip)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(m_nomVisitant==nomEquip)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Necesito comparar si el contenido de las varianles nomlocal y visitante son iguales al parametro nomEquip y retornar true de ser así y false en caso contrario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que te interesa es saber si `nomEquip` es equivalente a `m_nomLocal` o `m_nomVisitant` y suponiendo que las tres variables son de tipo `CCadena`, sería más natural dejarlo así:

```
if(m_nomLocal==nomEquip || m_nomVisitant==nomEquip)
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

o así:

```
return (m_nomLocal==nomEquip || m_nomVisitant==nomEquip);
```

Las dos opciones son equivalentes, por supuesto tu método también funcionaría, pero es más repetitivo y, por tanto, propenso a errores.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que `m_nomLocal`, `m_nomVisitant` y `nomEquip` son variables `const char`* mientras que el operador `==` que definio se utiliza para comparar objetos `CCadena`. Su operador `==` compara los miembros `m_pText` de las `CCadena`s y por lo tanto no sirve para comparar m_local, m_nomVisitant y nomEquip directamente.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class CCadena{
public:
    const char* m_pText;
    CCadena(const char* pText): m_pText(pText){}
    bool operator==(const CCadena& obj) const {
        return strcmp(m_pText, obj.m_pText) == 0;
    }
};

int main(){
    CCadena local("aaaa");
    CCadena equip("bbbb");
    std::cout << (local == equip) << std::endl;

    CCadena visitante("aaaa");
    std::cout << (local == visitante) << std::endl;
}
```